# Different iframe for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, responsive-design

I'm trying to add iframe to Wordpress pages. I want to display iframe A for desktop users and iframe B for mobile users, because some elements just don't work with mobile devices and at the same time I don't want to lose functionality for the desktop version. I'm pretty new to coding, so detailed explanation how to solve this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is using CSS media queries. `@media(max-width: 540px)` contains styles that will only apply on screens of width at most 540px (and you can change the number to whatever suits your needs).

And, I imagine you could do this too to the actual page pointed at by the iframe, so that you don't need two iframes in the first place. I.e. apply media queries directly to the page that has buttons to show/hide on mobile.

```css
/* mobile (you can change 540px to whatever breakpoint you like) */
@media(max-width: 540px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .mobile {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}

/* desktop */
@media(min-width: 541px) {
  .desktop {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid cyan;
  }
  
  .mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<iframe class="desktop"></iframe>

<iframe class="mobile"></iframe>
```